# Simple JavaScript won`t work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why isn't this working in Chrome?

HTML:

```
<div class="deo" id="a1">
<form id="formaA1" name="formaA1">
 KOLIKO JE 3-1+5? //It`s simple equation, it says: How much is 3-1+5?
<br/>
<input type="text" id="pitanjeA1" name="pitanjeA1" />
<br/>
<button onClick="return a1();">Odgovor</button>             
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .deo  {
    width: 24%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: #808080;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    }

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
function a1() {
    if (parseInt(document.formaA1.pitanjeA1.value) == 7) {
        document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = "<img src='zmaj_01.jpg'>";
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Netacan odgovor. \nPokusajte ponovo.");
        return false;
    }
}​
```

It`s a simple program, everytime child answers correct piece of image appears. 
It works fine in FireFox and IE, but in Chrome it does nothing.
Also, any critics on code is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using chromes javascript console? press ctrl+shift+J to access it and it should show any errors

Comment: Your code doesn't work in FF, IE or Chrome on my machine. Check your code as imulsion said but, for what you're trying to do, try using jQuery

Comment: I tried, it doesn`t show any errors. Also, alert message for wrong answer appears fine, it`s just that the right answer doesn`t do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.addEventListener` to attach your event, and `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from actually submitting when the user clicks on the button.
Also, when commenting HTML code, use the html comment syntax "`<!-- -->`" instead of "`//`"

Html:

```
<div class="deo" id="a1">
<form id="formaA1" name="formaA1">
 KOLIKO JE 3-1+5? <!-- It`s simple equation, it says: How much is 3-1+5? -->
<br/>
<input type="text" id="pitanjeA1" name="pitanjeA1" />
<br/>
<button id="submitButton">Odgovor</button>             
</form>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Js:

```
/* http://dustindiaz.com/rock-solid-addevent */
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        EventCache.add(obj, type, fn);
    }

    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
        obj[type + fn] = function() {
            obj["e" + type + fn](window.event);
        }
        obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
        EventCache.add(obj, type, fn);
    }
    else {
        obj["on" + type] = obj["e" + type + fn];
    }
}
var EventCache = function() {
    var listEvents = [];
    return {
        listEvents: listEvents,
        add: function(node, sEventName, fHandler) {
            listEvents.push(arguments);
        },
        flush: function() {
            var i, item;
            for (i = listEvents.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
                item = listEvents[i];
                if (item[0].removeEventListener) {
                    item[0].removeEventListener(item[1], item[2], item[3]);
                };
                if (item[1].substring(0, 2) != "on") {
                    item[1] = "on" + item[1];
                };
                if (item[0].detachEvent) {
                    item[0].detachEvent(item[1], item[2]);
                };
                item[0][item[1]] = null;
            };
        }
    };
}();
addEvent(window, 'load', function() {
    addEvent(document.getElementById("submitButton"), "click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
        if (parseInt(document.formaA1.pitanjeA1.value) == 7) {
            document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = "<img src='zmaj_01.jpg'>";
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Netacan odgovor. \nPokusajte ponovo.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});​
```

​[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfAr/5/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfAr/5/)

Comment: It`s not working. I get message: 'Cannot call method addEventListener of null".

Comment: Change your html code, and add the script at the end of the page

Comment: It is a good idea to use unobtrusive javascript, but it is not the problem here

Comment: Thanx a lot, this works great. Just one more question-I tried the same code in IE, changed addEventListener to attachEvent, but with no response. Any ideas on how to use your code in IE?

Comment: @beliluk See edit for cross browser solution, however using a library such as jQuery will really help in cases like this...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are reusing the a1 ID for the function name

Change `<div id="a1"` to `<div= id="a1Div"` or change the call and function

`<button onClick="return a1Func();">Odgovor</button>`

and

`function a1Func ...`

Here is inline version [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ne3PP/)

```
<div class="deo" id="a1Div">

<button onClick="return a1(this.form);">Odgovor</button>
```

using

```
function a1(theForm) {
  if (parseInt(theForm.pitanjeA1.value,10) === 7) {
    document.getElementById("a1Div").innerHTML="<img src='zmaj_01.jpg'>";
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Netacan odgovor. \nPokusajte ponovo.");
    return false;
  }
}​
```

same version unobtrusive [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/GtSbh/)

```
<button id="testBut">Odgovor</button>
```

using

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById("testBut").onclick=function() {
      if (parseInt(this.form.pitanjeA1.value,10) === 7) {
        document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML="<img src='zmaj_01.jpg'>";
        return true;
      } else {
        alert("Netacan odgovor. \nPokusajte ponovo.");
        return false;
      }
    }
}    ​
```